Issues with Generating Text from Fine-Tuned Mistral 7B Model on Georgian Dataset
I've fine-tuned the Mistral 7B model using a Georgian dataset with approximately 100,000 articles, including custom tokenizer fine-tuning. The fine-tuning process took about 9 hours. However, when I try to generate text, the output is not as expected; it consistently returns the input as the output, regardless of the input provided.
Here's the code I used for fine-tuning:
import time
import json
import torch
from datasets import Dataset
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, TrainingArguments

# Load dataset, preprocess, and fine-tuning details...

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="mistral_georgian_news_finetuning",
    max_steps=3125,
    per_device_train_batch_size=32,
    learning_rate=3e-4,
    # Other arguments...
)

# Fine-tuning setup...

# Start fine-tuning
trainer.train()

For testing the fine-tuned model, I used the following code:
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

model_path = "/path/to/fine-tuned-model"
tokenizer_path = "/path/to/tokenizer"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(tokenizer_path)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_path)

def generate_text(prompt_text, max_length=500):
    input_ids = tokenizer(prompt_text, return_tensors="pt").input_ids
    output = model.generate(input_ids, max_length=max_length)
    return tokenizer.decode(output[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

prompt = "რამდენიმე დღეში შესრულდება ..."
generated_text = generate_text(prompt)
print(generated_text)

During testing, the model just echoes the prompt without generating new text. Below are the logs observed:
config.json: 0%| | 0.00/571 [00:00<?, ?B/s]
model.safetensors.index.json: 0%| | 0.00/25.1k [00:00<?, ?B/s]
Downloading shards: 0%| | 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
model-00001-of-00002.safetensors: 0%| | 0.00/9.94G [00:00<?, ?B/s]
model-00002-of-00002.safetensors: 0%| | 0.00/4.54G [00:00<?, ?B/s]
Loading checkpoint shards: 0%| | 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
generation_config.json: 0%| | 0.00/116 [00:00<?, ?B/s]
Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:2 for open-end generation.

I am unsure if the issue lies in how I am loading and testing the model or if it is related to the fine-tuning process. The model should generate text based on the input prompt, but it returns the input as the output.
Has anyone experienced similar issues, or can someone spot what might be wrong with my approach?

Why did your formatting look like your question was generated by AI?

well because i am not native at English i asked chat to correct my question and return it to me and this is what I got. anyways do you know anything about this issue?

check if the prompt you are using to test has any EOS token. i had the same issue but i was following a specific chat template, removed the EOS token for eval and worked fine for me.

Let's refactor your testing code to ensure that the model and tokenizer are loaded correctly and that the generation process is functioning as expected. Here's the updated code:
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

model_path = "/path/to/fine-tuned-model"
tokenizer_path = "/path/to/tokenizer"

def load_model(model_path, tokenizer_path):
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(tokenizer_path)
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_path)
    return model, tokenizer

def generate_text(model, tokenizer, prompt_text, max_length=500):
    input_ids = tokenizer(prompt_text, return_tensors="pt").input_ids
    output = model.generate(input_ids, max_length=max_length)
    return tokenizer.decode(output[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

def main():
    model, tokenizer = load_model(model_path, tokenizer_path)

    prompt = "რამდენიმე დღეში შესრულდება ..."
    generated_text = generate_text(model, tokenizer, prompt)
    print("Generated Text:", generated_text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Make sure to replace "/path/to/fine-tuned-model" and "/path/to/tokenizer" with the actual paths to your fine-tuned model and tokenizer. This code ensures that the model and tokenizer are loaded correctly and that the text generation process is functioning as expected. If the issue persists, further investigation into the fine-tuning process and data quality may be necessary.
